# Android Emulator (+Google API) doesn't include Google-API since SDK 22.0 anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api

It worked with SDK/ADT 21, but now it looks strange.

I have quite a few emulators with API 7,8,10,16,17 and Google API. Since updating the SDK/ADT to 22 they seem no to include some Google APIs anymore (for example Google GCM).

(`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar`).

I've already recreated a few emulators, but nothing works so far.

It was just fine with Tools SDK/ADT 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a kind of buggy with Eclipse & Emulator. 
Now it works altogether.
What did help were mainly two things:

1. setting in  .android/avd/youavdfoldername/config.ini
   hw.mainKeys=yes (from =no) (don't ask me why, it is magic)
2. Clean&Rebuild&Restart Eclipse (the last - just in case).

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated to the latest version of tools? Are you targeting the api level + tools in the build preferences? I haven't had a problem.

Comment: Yes, the latest. I am not targeting 4.1.2 (no Google API). Gcm.jar with GCMRegistar is linked under Android Private Libraries.